# How to find the value of "k" in following condition?

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

For what values of $k$ the line $y=9x$ be the tangent to the curve $y=\frac{k e^{k \sqrt{x+1}}}{\sqrt{x+1}}$ at some point on the $xy-$plane with constraint that $x>-1$

options are given:

a) k>0
b) k>0 and k<1
c) k>1 and k<3
d) k>3

this can be done like by using condition as 
$$\begin{align}
 &\frac{dy}{dx}=9\\
 &= \frac{k e^{k \sqrt{x+1}}}{2\sqrt{x+1}}\left(\frac{k \sqrt{x+1}-1}{x+1} \right)\\
\end{align}$$

what to do next to find the value of k, how to use the given constraint does this use for only sqrt to be defined, thanks.

Comment: If $y$ is what you write, then the $dy/dx$ you write is wrong, and I think the options are strange (and the question is very difficult to solve). Is the $y$ you write correct in the first place?

Comment: Yes you pointed out correctly the derivative is incorrect

Comment: $k$ seems to take only finitely many values (maybe only one). However, each given option has infinitely many values for $k$. This is strange, I think. If you need the detail, I'll write that down.

Comment: @mathlove I corrected the derivative but still how can I conclude the value for k, that you said are finitely many. Help me little further I want to solve it myself.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the curve
$$\mathcal{T}=\left\{(x,y_T)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y_S=9x \right\}$$
must be the tangent of the curve
$$\mathcal{S}_k=\left\{(x,y_S)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y_S= \frac{k e^{k\sqrt{x+1}}}{\sqrt{x+1}}, x>-1 \right\}.$$

So, for this to be true, we need that 
\begin{align}
\exists (x^*,y_S^*)\in \mathcal{S} \text{ and } (x^*,y_T^*) \in \mathcal{T}
\; \text{s.t.} \; 
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} y_T \Big{|}_{(x^*,y_T^*)} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} y_S \Big{|}_{(x^*,y_S^*)}
\; \text{and} \; 
(x^*,y_T^*) = (x^*,y_S^*).
\end{align}

From there you should be able concluded your answer. As your equations look suspicious, I let the raw method here.

Answer (score 0):

*(too long for a comment)*

Let $(s,t)$ be the tangent point.

We have
$$y'=\frac{ke^{k\sqrt{x+1}}(k\sqrt{x+1}-1)}{2(x+1)^{3/2}}$$
so we want $k$ such that there exists $(s,t)$ satisfying
$$t=9s$$
$$t=\frac{ke^{k\sqrt{s+1}}}{\sqrt{s+1}}$$
$$\frac{ke^{k\sqrt{s+1}}(k\sqrt{s+1}-1)}{2(s+1)^{3/2}}=9$$
From these, we can represent $k$ by $s$ and have an equation on $s$, but solving it seems difficult.

Comment: thanks @mathlove I also find it difficult to solve or assume the value through given options and there must be a quick solution to it which we can not conceive, unless it is not given in a test where I supposed to do it in 1 min.

Comment: @Abomm: If you don't have any typo in the question, then I think I cannot help you. The options are strange, and I want to know the "correct option" if you know.

Comment: thanks@mathlove may be question is misprinted in the book it happens sometime no big deal thanks

Comment: @Abomm: Yes, it happens :) You are welcome.